# Reference a subfolder of Inbox

Tags: vba, excel

I want to extract text, from emails in an Outlook Folder named "FaxReceipt", to an Excel spreadsheet

I have created a column name "FaxReceipt". I want all text extracted into the Excel column.

```
Sub OutlookEMails1()
Dim ns As Namespace
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim myitem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim objSearchFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim item As Object
Dim mai As MailItem

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objSearchFolder = Inbox
i = 0
If Inbox.Items.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Inbox is Empty", vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
End If

For Each item In Inbox.Items
    vbody = item.Body
    Range("A2").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Loop
    ActiveCell.Value = vbody
Next

Set objSearchFolder = Nothing
Set Inbox = Nothing
Set ns = Nothing

End Sub
```

This code is only working on the default Inbox folder.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to alter your code to:

A. Set an object to the subfolder of Inbox (you already have a
    objSearchFolder - you just weren't using it.)

B. Look in that object instead of Inbox

```
Sub OutlookEMails1()
Dim ns As Namespace
Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
Dim myitem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim objSearchFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim item As Object
Dim mai As MailItem

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objSearchFolder = Inbox.Folders("faxreceipt")
i = 0

If objSearchFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Search Folder is Empty", vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
End If

For Each item In objSearchFolder.Items
    vbody = item.Body
    Range("A2").Select

    Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
        ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
    Loop
    ActiveCell.Value = vbody
Next

Set objSearchFolder = Nothing
Set Inbox = Nothing
Set ns = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much it working fine now.'

Comment: Glad I could help. If you're happy that we've answered your question then don't forget to mark one of the responses as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub OutlookEMails1()

Dim ns                  As Namespace
Dim Inbox               As MAPIFolder
Dim myitem              As Outlook.MailItem
Dim FileName            As String
Dim i                   As Integer
Dim objSearchFolder     As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim item                As Object
Dim mai                 As MailItem
Dim objFaxReceiptFolder As Object

Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set objSearchFolder = Inbox
Set objFaxReceiptFolder = Inbox.Folders("faxreceipt")
i = 0
If objFaxReceiptFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Folder Fax Receipt is Empty", vbInformation, "Nothing Found"
End If
For Each item In objFaxReceiptFolder.Items
    vbody = item.Body
Range("A2").Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""
    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select
Loop
    ActiveCell.Value = vbody
Next
Set objSearchFolder = Nothing
Set Inbox = Nothing
Set ns = Nothing

End Sub
```